# Class loading issue with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have a piece of code which works in one environment and fails with another one. For some reason a class loading fails. I ran the application with a -verbose flag to check for differences but I cannot find the reason.
The class causing problems is `org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration`

Other classes from the same library seem to be loaded without issues before.

This is a piece of output where the error occurs:

```
[52.212s][info][class,load  ] org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/SDK/Eclipse-workspaces/eclipse_2022-07/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/../../../../../../../git-repositories/knime-scripting/de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.libs/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar
[52.213s][info][class,load  ] org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler$Updater source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/SDK/Eclipse-workspaces/eclipse_2022-07/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/../../../../../../../git-repositories/knime-scripting/de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.libs/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[52.213s][info][class,load  ] org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler$9 source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/SDK/Eclipse-workspaces/eclipse_2022-07/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/../../../../../../../git-repositories/knime-scripting/de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.libs/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[52.213s][info][class,load  ] org.apache.commons.configuration2.convert.DefaultListDelimiterHandler source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/SDK/Eclipse-workspaces/eclipse_2022-07/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/../../../../../../../git-repositories/knime-scripting/de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.libs/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[52.213s][info][class,load  ] org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.EventListenerProvider source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/SDK/Eclipse-workspaces/eclipse_2022-07/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/../../../../../../../git-repositories/knime-scripting/de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.libs/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[52.213s][info][class,load  ] org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder$$Lambda$1498/0x0000000801c16698 source: org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder
[52.214s][info][class,load  ] org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder$1 source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/SDK/Eclipse-workspaces/eclipse_2022-07/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/../../../../../../../git-repositories/knime-scripting/de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.libs/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[52.214s][info][class,load  ] org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/SDK/Eclipse-workspaces/eclipse_2022-07/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/org.apache.commons.lang3_3.9.0.jar
FATAL    AWT-EventQueue-0 RGGDialogPanel     org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
[52.215s][info][class,load  ] java.lang.Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter source: jrt:/java.base
[52.215s][info][class,load  ] java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream source: jrt:/java.base
org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.fetchBeanClass(BeanHelper.java:427)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBeanCreationContext(BeanHelper.java:475)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:353)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:371)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:383)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder.createResultInstance(BasicConfigurationBuilder.java:361)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder.createResult(BasicConfigurationBuilder.java:338)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(BasicConfigurationBuilder.java:234)
    at at.ac.arcs.rgg.RGG.initRGG(Unknown Source)
```

while this is a piece of output where I do not get any error:

```
[45.850s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/git-repositories/rgg/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar
[45.919s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler$Updater source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/git-repositories/rgg/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[45.919s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler$9 source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/git-repositories/rgg/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[45.948s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.configuration2.convert.DefaultListDelimiterHandler source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/git-repositories/rgg/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[45.955s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.EventListenerProvider source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/git-repositories/rgg/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[248.267s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder$$Lambda$144/0x0000000800d03740 source: org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder
[248.280s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder$1 source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/git-repositories/rgg/lib/commons-configuration2-2.8.0.jar
[248.313s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils source: file:/Users/niederle/knimeDev/git-repositories/rgg/lib/commons-lang3-3.9.jar
[248.316s][info][class,load] java.lang.NumberFormatException source: jrt:/java.base
[248.325s][info][class,load] java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/0x0000000800d06000 source: __JVM_LookupDefineClass__
[248.326s][info][class,load] java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[248.335s][info][class,load] java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/0x0000000800d06400 source: __JVM_LookupDefineClass__
[248.340s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration$$Lambda$145/0x0000000800d07000 source: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
[248.345s][info][class,load] org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration$$Lambda$146/0x0000000800d07220 source: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
```

I am not sure whether this is the right way to troubleshoot or whether it gives me some hint but I don't see it. I would be happy if anybody could help troubleshooting.
Do I need to provide more information? Jars provided should be the same in both environments.

---

EDIT:

I went on with troubleshooting and still don't get the problem.

This is the piece of code causing trouble. While class loading with `Class.forName()` seems to work, the second part of the code fails with the error mentioned above. In the second part, the class is attempted to be loaded somewhere within `builder.getConfiguration()` via `beanutils`.

```java
config = new CompositeConfiguration();
try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    System.out.println("failed to load class");
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder =
        new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                    .configure(new Parameters().properties()
                    .setURL(RGG.class.getResource("/at/ac/arcs/rgg/config/elementfactory.properties"))
                    .setThrowExceptionOnMissing(true)
                    .setListDelimiterHandler(new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(';'))
                    .setIncludesAllowed(false));
System.out.println("builder initialized");
PropertiesConfiguration newConfig;
try {
    newConfig = builder.getConfiguration();
    config.addConfiguration(newConfig);
} catch (ConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this is a library access issue. How would I troubleshoot?

The setup where it fails is the following: The code is part of a jar which is used as a library for an Eclipse plugin (me as author) written for a RCP application (not from me).

Comment: I think it is about maven build. Check the dependencies.

Comment: Looks like your environment don't have access to that library, check your artifactory or your .jar

Comment: @AL wouldn't that mean that all classes from that library would have that problem? Other classes from `org.apache.commons.configuration2` are loaded without problems before.

Comment: Not necessary, many times that happens to me, just a few dependencies fail, because I have the repository from other projects, or because the settings.xml try to pull from the maven central, I really think the problem its the access to the artifactory you are using, or maybe they use different version between libraries, and that diff between versions have changes in the package.

Comment: @AL   I am afraid I don't get where to start. I'd like to be able to check access but I have no idea how.

Comment: Well, I guess you should ask to your devops or the department which gives access to the repository, idk if you use artifactory or what, because I don't know if you are trying to do this for personal purpose, or for a company. But if you don't know, probably its something related with ur company, so, try to find the department and ask for the list of libraries they have in the environment you need.

Comment: @AL I am doing it for my own. No company behind. So, I should be able to adapt my environment. I simply don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could solve my issue

I made some mistake here: The full stack trace could have been useful for troubleshooting. Further the setup (not working within an Eclipse plugin) seemed to play an important role.

As far as I understood it, the issue has been caused like this:

`RGG.jar` (library within my plugin) is dependent on `commons-configuration` (library in my plugin). But then within `commons-configuration` a class from the same package has to be loaded with `ClassUtils` of `commons-lang`. But `commons-lang` is provide from outside as `Required Plug-ins`. It seems that it cannot access this class from outside.

The solution I found was to add `commons-lang` as a library to that plugin and delete the dependency. Now class loading works.